# How to do addition of time in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, time, addition

I was wondering why I can't make the correct result of addition of time, e.g.: 3:11:0 from 2:50:20 + 0:20:40, however I only got something like 3:10:0.  So, below is my work;

```
    //variable
    int hour, min, sec;
    int hour1, min1, sec1;
    int total, total1, total2;
    int total11,total12, total21, total22;

    //input1
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input hours\t: ");
    hour = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input minutes\t: ");
    min = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input seconds\t: ");
    sec = input.nextInt();

    //output1
    System.out.println("Time 1 is " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec);

    //input2
    System.out.print("Input additional hours\t: ");
    hour1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input additional minute\t: ");
    min1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Input additional seconds\t: ");
    sec1 = input.nextInt();

    //output2
    System.out.println("Time 2 is " + jam1 + ":" + menit1 + ":" + detik1);

    //process
    total = hour + hour1;
    total1 = min + min1;
    total11 = total1/60;
    total12 = total11%60;
    total2 = sec + sec1;
    total21 = total2/60;
    total22 = total2%60;

    if (total1 > 60) {
    total1 = (min + min1) - 60;
        total = (hour + hour1) + total11;
        total2 = (sec + sec1)-60;
    }
    if (total2 > 60) {
        total2 = (sec + sec1) - 60;
        total1 = (min + min1) + total22;
    }
    //finaloutput
    System.out.println("Your total time is  " + total + ":" + total1 + ":" + total2);
```

*Sorry about the grammar :) I really appreciate your answer :)

Comment: Isn't that the right answer? Are you asking how come you're formatting it incorrectly?

Comment: You have a typo: `total1 = (min + min1) + total22;` should be `total1 = (min + min1) + total21;`

Comment: Your code example doesn't compile - where are `jam1`, `menit1` and `detik1` defined? Also, `total1`, `total11`, `total21` etc. are terrible variable names. Describe what they are, don't just add numbers to the end.

Comment: @Pablo You may be correct, but that doesn't fix the overall problem.

Comment: I'm really sorry that there are lots of typo, because I kind of translate this from indonesia to english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way that I have found to do these things is to convert both times to seconds (so convert 3:11:00 to 11460 seconds past midnight), add/subtract them, and then convert back to hh:mm:ss. Roughly:

```
int time1 = (hours1 * 60 + min1) * 60 + sec1;
int time2 = (hours2 * 60 + min2) * 60 + sec2;
int total = time1 + time2;
short hour = total / 3600;
short minute = total / 60 % 60;
short second = total %60;
```

Comment: This is definitely the correct way to approach the problem, assuming that standard library methods are not allowed.

Comment: Thanks! I had also try this and I got right answer, once again thank you!:)

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
        int totalHour, totalMin, totalSec, totalTemp;
        totalSec = sec + sec1;
        totalMin = (totalSec / 60) + min + min1;
        totalHour = (totalMin / 60) + hour + hour1;
        totalSec = totalSec % 60;
        totalMin = totalMin % 60;
        if(totalHour != 12)
        {
            totalHour = totalHour % 12;
        }


        //finaloutput
        System.out.println("Your total time is  " + totalHour + ":" + totalMin + ":" + totalSec);
```

This will take each value starting with seconds and calculate the totals based on if there is overflow from the lower one ie. seconds -> minutes -> hours.  Then it will calculate the actual seconds minutes and hours based on the remainder of the previous caluclations...

Comment: Thanks! I had try this and I got right answer, once again thank you!:)